# Disable app nap in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

How do I disable app nap in Swift? Im new to programming and I am building a timer(just for practice), and I am afraid app nap will break my timer.

Comment: Not sure what the app nap is but are you looking for [idleTimerDisabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled)?

Comment: idleTimerDisabled seems to only work on iOS App. Mine is OSX application. AppNap is a technology that apple introduced with Mavericks OS X to low energy consumption

Comment: My bad, didn't notice OS X tag.

Answer (score 8):

I found that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847293/disable-app-nap-in-macos-10-9-mavericks-application?rq=1) works in Swift as well.

Create a class or global variable

```
var activity: NSObjectProtocol?
```

And assign it after which App Nap will be disabled

```
activity = NSProcessInfo().beginActivityWithOptions(NSActivityOptions.UserInitiated, reason: "Good Reason")
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**:

```
var activity: NSObjectProtocol?
```

and

```
activity = ProcessInfo().beginActivity(options: ProcessInfo.ActivityOptions.userInitiated, reason: "Good Reason")
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.x / 5.3**:

For `ProcessInfo.ActivityOptions`, Apple's documentation describes:

> `static var userInitiated`
>
> Flag to indicate the app is performing a user-requested action.
>
> `static var userInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep`
>
> Flag to indicate the app is performing a user-requested action, but that the system can sleep on idle.

Unless your intention is to prevent the system from sleeping, you should use  `userInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep`.

**Steps**

1. Retain reference in a scope that will survive until any point you may want to revert the change (ie: within `AppDelegate`)

   ```
    var activity: NSObjectProtocol?
   ```
2. Run this, possibly in AppDelegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

   ```
    activity = ProcessInfo.processInfo.beginActivity(options: .userInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep, reason: "Good Reason")
   ```

To cancel and re-enable App Nap at any time:

```
if let pinfo = activity {
    ProcessInfo.processInfo.endActivity(pinfo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous 3 answers to this question correctly use `ProcessInfo` class. As per `ProcessInfo` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo):

> Each process has a single, shared `ProcessInfo` object, known as a *process information agent*. The `processInfo` type property [previously class method] returns the shared agent for the current process.

`processInfo` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1408734-processinfo) explains it further:

> The object is created the first time this property [previously method] is invoked, and that same object is returned on each subsequent invocation.

Otherwise you refer to different instances of `ProcessInfo` object when beginning and ending activity (you must end activity), what can lead to incorrect behaviour. Thus the correct code in Swift 5 is:

```swift
let activity = ProcessInfo.processInfo.beginActivity(options: .userInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep, reason: "Timer")
// Perform some work
ProcessInfo.processInfo.endActivity(activity)
```

---

While the details of the app and timer implementation are unknown, it's hard to say whether this approach is correct in your case. Please also consider these notes:

> If your activity takes place synchronously inside an event callback on the main thread, you do not need to use this API.
>
> Be aware that failing to end these activities for an extended period of time can have significant negative impacts to the performance of your user's computer, so be sure to use only the minimum amount of time required. User preferences may override your application’s request.

Usage of `Timer` object (and bringing in some tolerance if possible) may be a more correct approach. System (and its App Nap feature) should account for the timer. Testing and Activity Monitor will tell you.