# Swift & macOS: Timer works with delay when app works in background

Tags: swift, macos, timer, swift3, macos-sierra

I have an macOS app that have timer and increase number every second. Every 60 second I show a notification with some message.

I found that my macOS Swift app runs with some delay, and after ~10 minutes started to sleep (no new a;lets appear anymore).

I have found some solutions, like this:

```
private func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: 1.0,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(timerTick),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true
    )
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}
```

But this command don't helped me to fix the lag with background run of timer:
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

Need some experienced Swift guy who can help me to solve this interesting challenge. I need to count seconds in background app correctly, because my app shows alert messages every few minutes, and if it can't show me these alerts correctly - my app will work not as I expected.

Thank you!

Comment: Sound like you might be running into Apple's App Nap feature ( http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/os-x-10-9/13/ ).  Instead of scheduling a once-per-second repeating timer and incrementing a counter, you might be better off scheduling a single-shot timer that will call your callback just once, after a few minutes, at which point you can schedule the next timer callback.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653939/disable-app-nap-in-swift.

Comment: Still didn't found solution for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you're running into [App Nap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013207-CH100). You do have some control about telling the system your process should not be wound down with App Nap via [NSProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsprocessinfo).

You may also be able to try to disable App Nap `defaults write <app domain name> NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES`... but not sure if that still works or not (App Nap was introduced in OS X 10.9, so the three years time may have disabled the disable function...)