# Disable App Nap for Mono Mac application

Tags: macos, mono

I'd like App Nap to be disabled by default for my Mono Mac application as it ships.

I've found a few references to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847293/disable-app-nap-in-macos-10-9-mavericks-application?rq=1), but `NSProcessInfo.beginActivityWithOptions` doesn't appear to exist in the MonoMac classes.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with MonoMac or Xamarin.Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the Activity object that is returned from `BeginActivity` somewhere:

```
NSObject myActivity;
const string myReason = "Hacking the planet";
```

Then when you want to prevent app nap from occuring:

```
// Prevent auto-sleeping
myActivity = new NSProcessInfo().BeginActivity(NSActivityOptions.IdleSystemSleepDisabled|NSActivityOptions.SuddenTerminationDisabled, myReason);
```

There are lots of combinations of [NSActivityOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html) that you can use depending upon your application requirements.

And when you are done with your processing:

```
// End the battery draining activty
new NSProcessInfo().EndActivity(myActivity);
```

Comment: It's a MonoMac project, and still supporting 10.6 (!). I might have to fork it off for the newer versions.