# Xamarin Mac server becomes slow when main window is inactive

Tags: macos, server

I am currently developing a Mac OS X server application that  processes a screenshot and sends it to a client over wifi. It all works very well, but I've noticed that the frame rate with which I am able to take and send screenshots is reduced by almost a factor 20 when the server main window is inactive for a few seconds. I have the feeling that this is an OS related feature/issue. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a lot like what the [App Nap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap.html) feature could cause.

Recommendation is to programmatically disable it as already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847293/disable-app-nap-in-macos-10-9-mavericks-application).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it!